# How to invert f curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

So I am currently making an audio visualiser and I want it so that when a specific frequency hits the object will be black. Currently, whenever a specific frequency hits it is white. This means I have to invert the f curves. Is there a way to do this?[image]

Comment: When you say 'frequency', you mean a specific pitch or tone, right? If the curve in your sample image is the waveform curve, you'd have to compute the Discrete Fourier Transform on the curve in order to transform the audio into the frequency domain. However, the result would not be a 2D F-Curve, but a 3D surface.

Comment: Yeah. I have the same problem, except that I need to change the shape of something. Is there a way to invert the f-curves themselves?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to inverting the curve is inverting how the curve affects the material. The curve will remain the same but the resulting colors will be inverted.

Create a value node and create a keyframe for it. Bake the sound curve to it.

[image]

After that you can invert the values with an invert node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't work. Nothing happens to the shape.

Comment: the shape of the curve won't change, but how it affects  the colors of the material (at what point is black or white) will.